# How to set up a local LESS environment

Tags: less, installation, local, development-environment, pre-compilation

How would you set up a local environment that would allow you to see LESS in-browser, locally? So far, I can only get it to work from a remote server, and it's totally aggravating. I've downloaded SimpLESS, and it's done virtually nothing for me. I can't sort out what the issue is, but I figure that if loads of people use LESS, there's got to be a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by “allow you to see LESS in-browser”? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use [less.js](http://lesscss.org/#usage), the official LESS development. But beware that this is not a good idea if not for simply local testing.

Another way you have to see your LESS "in-browser" is using the [LESS Live Preview](http://less2css.org/) tool.